# Retrofit2 использование клиента одновременно для JSON запросов и закачки файлов

Tags: android, retrofit

До сих пор использовал `Retrofit2` для обработки запросов, в которых приходил `JSON`. Для этого в синглтоне добавил конвертер `GsonConverterFactory`. Теперь возникла необходимость загружать файлы с сервера. Могу я адаптировать существующий клиент для этого? сейчас он пытается распарсить входящий `byteArray` как будто это `json`, а мне хочется обрабатывать его как `ResponseBody`, при этом не уходя от возможности тем же клиентом парсить `json`.

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо просто указать, что метод, запрашивающий файл должен возвращать тип ResponseBody

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Увы, нет, он именно и пытался в респонс боди распарсить входные данные, при помощи GsonConverterFactory. Пришлось сделать свой ConverterFactory и отдельный клиент для закачки, так как один клиент позволяет добавлять только одну фабрику